# C++ unique_ptr vector

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have the following line of code

```
SystemFactory::system_ptr system = _Factory->createSystem(systemType);
_Systems.push_back(std::move(system));
```

The problem that I have is I can't just return the **system** as it will NULL it after moving it.
The solution that I came with is the following and I don't know if it's the best one.

```
return (_Systems.end() - 1)->get();
```

If there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: Names like `_Factory` and `_Systems` are IIRC [reserved for the implementation in all scopes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/212858).

Comment: OT: `_Systems` is an implementation reserved identifier, you cannot use it. Also, starting variable names with an uppercase letter is somewhat uncommon.

Comment: Link to rules for naming [identifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers).

Comment: Well, what are you trying to do? You didn't actually say.

Answer (score 8):

You can either use `back()`:

```
return _Systems.back().get();
```

... or save it beforehand:

```
SystemFactory::system_ptr system = _Factory->createSystem(systemType);
auto *p = system.get();
_Systems.push_back(std::move(system));
return p;
```

Answer (score 4):

In C++17, [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) will return a *reference* to the emplaced object. Therefore you'll be able to write:

```
SystemFactory::system_ptr system = _Factory->createSystem(systemType);
return _Systems.emplace_back(std::move(system));
```

Or even shorter:

```
return _Systems.emplace_back(_Factory->createSystem(systemType));
```